# How do I get an animated gif to work in WPF dictionary without codebehind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animated-gif

I have a dictionary that uses a datatemplate of another class,
the dictionary doen't have a code behind it's just XAML

i need to have a live animated gif as a part of this dictionary.

tried to do this:

```
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("myprojectname.Resources.theGifToUse.gif");
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
picturebox = image;
```

and in the XAML:

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
   <forms:PictureBox x:Name="pictu1rebox" Image="{Binding picturebox}"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

but it doesn't work!

what is the most simple way to do it not using WpfAnimatedGif.dll?

thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Standard `BitmapImage` does not support playback of `.gif` files. The only option that I know is to use a `Bitmap`. It has `ImageAnimator`. Full example:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="PlayGifHelp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded">

    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="SampleImage" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Bitmap _bitmap;
    BitmapSource _source;

    private BitmapSource GetSource()
    {
        if (_bitmap == null)
        {
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            // Check the path to the .gif file
            _bitmap = new Bitmap(path + @"\anim.gif");
        }

        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        handle = _bitmap.GetHbitmap();

        return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _source = GetSource();
        SampleImage.Source = _source;
        ImageAnimator.Animate(_bitmap, OnFrameChanged);
    }

    private void FrameUpdatedCallback()
    {
        ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();

        if (_source != null)
        {
            _source.Freeze();
        }

        _source = GetSource();

        SampleImage.Source = _source;
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private void OnFrameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(FrameUpdatedCallback));
    }
}
```

`Bitmap` does not support `URI` directive, so I load `.gif` file from the current directory.

Comment: this is not a window XAML, it is a ResourceDictionary XAML so it doesn't help me

Comment: You asked for the implementation of the play the `.gif` file without any external library. Well, I do not know any way to do it and I have not seen more examples.